# How to adjust the height and width of the chart as per my div height and width

Tags: html, charts, plotly, height

I am plotting chart using plotly in python.

The chart is appearing but the scroller coming in the page I dont want the scroller .

[image: ChartImage]

```
 labels = df['Labels']
                  values=df['Value']
                  # values = df.iloc[:, 6].tolist() #make it dynamic
                  # labels = df.iloc[:, 5].tolist() #make it dynamic
                  fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values)])
                  fig.update_layout(
                      autosize=False,
                      width = 500,
                      height = 300,
                      legend=dict(
                          orientation='h',
                          x=0.5,
                          y=-0.2,
                          traceorder='normal',
                          xanchor='center',
                          font=dict(size=10),itemwidth=30
                      )
                  )
                  
                  plot_div = plotly.offline.plot(fig, output_type='div')
                  return plot_div
```